# ImportError when importing pytorch

Tags: python, import, keras, pytorch

When I try importing pytorch inside a jupyter notebook i get the following error:

> ImportError: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
>   pytorch

```
import torch
```

No error when i import torch from command line (not jupyter notebook)

Comment: Have you already checked out https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2083 ?

Comment: Yes. I think i have a different kind of problem as i get the error message even when i just import only pytorch and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons i cannot yet explain, i found out that this is happening only when i install Keras too in the same virtual environment, and it goes away when i uninstall Keras.

So the solution was

```
pip uninstall keras
```